# MySQL: calculate average (drop the lowest two) after group by

Tags: mysql

guys, I have a problem below. Could you help me solve this? Thank you so much.

```
create table grades ( student varchar(4), assign varchar(4), grade int);

insert into grades values ( 's01','a05',4), ('s01','a06',3),('s02','a04',6),('s02','a05',4),( 's01','a04', 9),( 's02','a01', 9),('s02','a02',8),('s02','a03',9), ( 's01','a01', 9), ( 's01','a02', 7),( 's01','a03', 7) ;
```

Professor maintains grades as shown above and has agreed to drop two lowest scores and take the average.
write a query to computer the average for each student as shown below

```
<SAMPLE_OUTPUT>
+---------+--------------+
| student | avg(O.grade) |
+---------+--------------+
| s01     |       8.0000 |
| s02     |       8.6667 |
+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: Can you provide the results for all students

Comment: Hmmm.... a `having` clause might simplify the answers shown

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to give all grades for each student a rank and then compute the average for grades over a certain rank. The `count(*)` in the derived table is used to ensure students with less than three grades still get averaged (in the case of 3 grades the two lowest are eliminated).

```
SELECT 
    a.student,     
    AVG(CASE
        WHEN c > 2 AND rank > 2 THEN grade
        WHEN c <= 2 THEN grade
    END) avg
FROM (SELECT student, COUNT(*) c FROM grades GROUP BY student) a
JOIN (
  SELECT 
    student,
    grade, 
    (CASE student
       WHEN @curType THEN @curRow:=@curRow + 1
       ELSE @curRow:=1 AND @curType:=student
     END
    ) + 1 AS rank
  FROM
  grades p, (SELECT @curRow:=0, @curType:='') r
  ORDER BY student , grade ASC
) b ON a.student = b.student
GROUP BY student;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5972/1)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested in MySQL, though should be relatively similar from this MSSQL chunk (limit instead of top, + 0.0 instead of cast etc.) - I've added an ID field to your table (can be replicated without table structure change with a pre-query for a temp table or WITH..AS statement):

```
create table grades (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), student varchar(4), assign varchar(4), grade int);

insert into grades values ( 's01','a05',4), ('s01','a06',3),('s02','a04',6),('s02','a05',4),( 's01','a04', 9),( 's02','a01', 9),('s02','a02',8),('s02','a03',9), ( 's01','a01', 9), ( 's01','a02', 7),( 's01','a03', 7) 


select distinct i.student,
(select avg(cast(ii.grade as float)) from grades ii where ii.id in (
select top (select 
case count(*)
when 0 then 0
when 1 then 1
when 2 then 2
else count(*) - 2
end
from grades iii where iii.student= i.student) ii.ID from grades ii where  ii.student = i.student order by ii.grade desc))
from grades i
```

The case statement is to be sure that if there are two or less records for the student, it won't drop those grades off - the "worst two being dropped" case is handled for students with three or more tests in the system.

If grouping is a requirement, you can handle this differently, as no grouping was needed for this solution.

Edit: I was editing this to run in MySQL, as this is in MSSQL, however another answer is working for MySQL, so I'll just leave this here for any MSSQL peeps with the same question.

Comment: Good point about the handling of students with two or fewer grades; I didn't think of that.

Comment: I would upvote your answer jpw, however I'm pretty new here and don't have the required reputation to vote yet - but you'll have one coming your way once I do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way (but I think jpw's method is faster)...

```
SELECT student,MAX(avg_grade) avg_grade
  FROM 
     ( SELECT student, AVG(grade) avg_grade FROM grades GROUP BY student
        UNION ALL
       SELECT a.student
            , AVG(grade) avg_grade
         FROM grades a
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT student
                   , GROUP_CONCAT(grade ORDER BY grade) grades
                FROM grades 
               GROUP 
                  BY student
            ) b
           ON b.student = a.student
        WHERE FIND_IN_SET(a.grade,b.grades) > 2
        GROUP 
           BY student
      ) x
  GROUP
     BY student;
```